# PhoneGap/WP8 - Fail to load url with parameters

Tags: cordova, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I'm trying to create an app on Windows Phone 8 with Cordova 3.3.0.

I create a new app Cordova 3.3.0. Then i change the file 'index.html' to include 'js/index.js' like that :

- before : <script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>
- after :  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js?rev=15"></script>

The script is never loaded when i add some parameters in the URL.

Any idea please ?

Thanks by advance,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Windows Phone platform Cordova server always returns status 404 when try to get a page with any type of params.
It not works with get params (?key=value) nor as location hash (#param).

Comment: So how to port jQuery Mobile/Sencha Touch on that phone ?
Sencha Touch adds a parameter with a random number as value to avoid cache when including scripts... :(

Comment: What if disable cache busting:
http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?203169-Disable-cache-busting-suffix-for-local-dev

Answer (score 1):

pages with .js extension should not be taking any parameters.

Comment: The same behavior happens when i put a link with parameters like that : <a href="index.html?rev=15">click here</a>

Answer (score 1):

Try using `js/index15.js` instead.

Answer (score 0):

This is only possible by accessing `own`  element in the HTML DOM and parse the src attribute.

here's a nice article with detailed explanations and code samples:
http://feather.elektrum.org/book/src.html